# R distr: * operator and multiplication of random variables

Tags: r, distribution

For a simulation, I need to compute the distribution of the product of two discrete random variables. Although I could implement it from scratch, I thought that the `distr` package already provides this functionality.

The operatorsIimplemented in the package do not seem to be documented, but, by trying, I have figured out that `+` stands for the convolution operation (sum of independent random variables):

```
> X <- DiscreteDistribution(supp=c(-1,0,1), prob=c(0.25,0.5,0.25))
> Y <- X + X
> attr(Y, "support")
[1] -2 -1  0  1  2
> d(Y)(attr(Y, "support"))
[1] 0.0625 0.2500 0.3750 0.2500 0.0625
```

Although there seems to be a multiplication operator (at least `methods(class="DiscreteDistribution")` reports one), it does not work as expected (actually, it does not work at all):

```
> Y <- X * X
Error in apply(mixDistr.dfs, 1, all) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Does someone know how to compute the distribution of the product of two discrete independent random variables with `distr`? Or does the package lack this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this was a bug in `distr`.

As @allan-cameron points out, the operators for distributions are documented with `?'operators-methods'`. There is a multiplication operator listed for arbitrary distributions (class `AcDcLcDistribution`), and this indeed works for most cases:

```
> X <- DiscreteDistribution(1:2)
> Y <- DiscreteDistribution(1:2)
> Z <- X*Y
> support(Z)
[1] 1 2 4
> prob(Z)
   1    2    4 
0.25 0.50 0.25
```

My example did not work due to a bug in `distr`. I have reported it to the maintainers of `distr`, and the bug will be fixed in the upcoming release 2.9.3.

Answer (score 1):

The methods for the mathematical operators *are* documented. Look up

```r
?distr::`operators-methods`
```

and you will find a description for how the operators works on different classes within the package.

There is a single signature for `*` involving the "DiscreteDistribution" class:

> `*`   signature(e1 = "DiscreteDistribution", e2 = "numeric") result of class "AffLinDiscreteDistribution"

This can be demonstrated by doing:

```r
X * 2
#> Distribution Object of Class: AffLinDiscreteDistribution
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that I must implement the functionality myself. What is the meaning of the backtics in the help command?

Comment: @cdalitz the backticks tell the R parser that `operators-methods` is a single symbol. If you typed ```distr::operators-methods``` then R would try to look up an object called `distr::operators`, another called `methods`, and try to subtract one from the other.

Comment: I was wondering why `?"operators-methods"` works, but neither of `?"distr::operators-methods"` `distr::"operators-methods"`. It seems that backticks can be used to quote just a part of a string. Or it is something in the parsing of  `?package::function`, which is translated to `help("function", package="package")`.

Comment: Yes, you can look at the code for the `?` function by typing a question mark surrounded by backticks into the console. Namespace-qualified topics like `?package::function` are specifically parsed to call `help("function", package = "package")`, but only if `function` is an unquoted _name_, i.e. it isn't a character string, so `distr::"operators-methods"` won't work. `?"distr::operators-methods"` isn't parsed as a call, so we get `help("distr::operators-methods")`, and of course there is no help topic called `"distr::operators-methods"`

Comment: A closer look at the documentation of `operators-methods` shows, that `*` actually *should be* implmented for distributions (signature `(e1 = "AcDcLcDistribution", e2 =          "AcDcLcDistribution")`). Actually, many other examples work. I have contacted the maintainer of `distr`, and he confirmed that the error should not occur and is a bug, which will be fixed in the next release of `distr`. I will add an answer summarizing this to avoid the false impression that `*` is not implemented.